# symfony input without name

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to implement a payment system in my website with Symfony.

I have to add a form, which takes the creditcard number. But I don't want this number coming to my server. So I need to do a form in which no name attribute is specified. So the server cannot take this value and I read the value directly by javascript.

Does Anybody know how to do a form without name?

If I do:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->add('creditNum', 'text')
                ->getForm();
```

This automatically creates a name attribute.

Comment: You want to handle credit cards numbers with Javascript? You could also `.removeAttr('name')` directly with jQuery.

Comment: yes, but that's not the problem. I want to make a input text without the name attribut.

Comment: Then how are you supposed to read the value of it? Lack of name attribute means that you won't be able to bind it to form data or anything of the matter. And since providing a name for a field is a required parameter when using form builder, you better "hard code" your input in your template.

Comment: If you're just trying to put an input box which you don't need to submit it to the server then why not just create it in twig (assuming you're using twig) file manually? and then take the value through javascript.

Comment: @ Artamiel: That's the idea, in my php file it isn't possible to take this value. I don't need to take a value in my server. Via javascript the value is directly taken by the payement server, the value is never transited by my own server. Is a security reason. "hard code", that's a solution, that's the unique solution?

Comment: @Dipen Shah: If it's the unique solution, I will do that!

Comment: I suppose since you're not taking care of that specific input field.

Comment: I am not sure how making a credit card number through javascript and so on is helpful with security. If you need to attach it to another provider do that not within your browser but your frameworks business logic. Guzzle for example can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could think about creating two separate forms, one form for your order form, and one form that just contains the credit card field(s). That way you can still handle the payment processing via Javascript, and when the user submits the main order form, the credit card field is not part of it, and won't be submitted to your server.

You'd probably have to use Javascript (or some really tricky CSS) to display the two forms nicely, so you might as well just create the credit card field with Javascript outside of the form itself, and position it so it looks like it's part of the form.